# $e^{itH}$ notation

Tags: notation, wave-equation, semigroup-of-operators, dispersive-pde

recently I saw the notation $e^{itH}$, and just wondering how should I interpret it?

In my understanding, $u(t,x) = e^{itH} u_0$ is, for example, a solution to
Schrodinger-type equation $i\partial_tu = -H u$ with the initial data $u_0$. In case $H = \Delta$, the solution to Schrodinger equation is known to involve the Schrodinger kernel in the integrand.
In such case, does $e^{itH}$ is a short-hand notation for the operator involving the Schrodinger kernel?

Or should I interpret $e^{itH}$ as the Taylor series with $H^k$ terms involved? In this case, does the (operator) series converge once applied to the element in the domain of $H$?

Also, I would be very glad to get a reference to read more on this type of operators. Thank you very much!

Comment: Modulo convergence issues those interpretations are equivalent. The convergence issues are fine as long as $H$ is bounded but of course for physically interesting examples that won't be the case.

Comment: thanks! any references to read more on this?

Comment: This isn't my area of expertise but this Wikipedia page and its references might be a good place to start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%27s_theorem_on_one-parameter_unitary_groups

Comment: many thanks!!!!

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2777051/70305)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be a real or complex Banach space, and let $\mathcal{L}(X)$ denote the bounded linear operators on $X$. A $C^0$ semigroup on $X$ is a function
$$
                    T : [0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathcal{L}(X)
$$
such that
\begin{align}
                (i) & \;\;\; T(0) = I, \\
                (ii) & \;\;\; T(t)T(t')=T(t+t'), \\
                (iii) & \;\;\; \lim_{t\downarrow 0}T(t)x = x,\;\; \forall x \in X.
\end{align}
For any such operator, let $\mathcal{D}(A)$ denote the set of all $\in X$ for which the following limit exists
$$
                             \lim_{h\downarrow 0} \frac{1}{h}(T(h)x-x),
$$
and let $Ax$ denote this limit. Then $H : \mathcal{D}(A)\subseteq X\rightarrow X$ is a densely-defined linear operator, and we write $T(t)=e^{tA}$ to summarize these properties.

If $T(t)$ is unitary for all $t > 0$, then $A=iH$, where $H$ is self-adjoint. Then it is customary to write $T(t) = e^{itH}$. This is typical of the time-invariant Schrodinger equation, for example. For such an operator, there is the Borel functional calculus, where $f(H)=$ is defined for any Borel measurable function on $\mathbb{R}$. Using this, $e^{itH}=f(H)$ where $f(s)=e^{its}$.

Answer (score 3):

The underlying Hilbert space has an orthonormal basis consisting of eigenfunctions $u_\lambda$ of $H$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then $e^{itH}u_\lambda:=e^{it\lambda}u_\lambda$. Forcing $e^{itH}$ to be linear and continuous then determines $e^{itH}u$ in general.

Answer (score 2):

From functional calculus, your operator is computed by a Taylor series as you say:  exp(itH)=1+itH+(itH)^2/2!+(itH)^3/3!...

Further reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_functional_calculus#Need_for_a_general_functional_calculus

Comment: This leads to convergence problems, as the OP guesses, since $H$ is unbounded.